# Nginx together with haproxy does not point the root index.php file

Tags: php, nginx, haproxy

I have 1 local **haproxy** server (10.10.1.18) that is used for loadbalance 2 nginx local webservers (**web1**=10.10.1.21,**web2**=10.10.1.22).

I can reach local ips of web servers to the index.php file successfully like that http://10.10.1.21/ and http://10.10.1.22/

However, when I point local ip of haproxy http://10.10.1.18/, it only brings the ***index.html*** file instead of ***index.php*** file.  We also have a domainname that points the public ip to the haproxy but http://example.uni.edu brings again the index.html file and not index.php file

So I don't think it's about public vs local ip  but rather haproxy or nginx configuration

**/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg**

```
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
    # full configuration options online.
    #
    #   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
    #
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Global settings
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    global
        # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
        # need to:
        #
        # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
        #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
        #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
        #
        # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
        #   file. A line like the following can be added to
        #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
        #
        #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
        #
        log         127.0.0.1 local2

        chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
        pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
        maxconn     10000
        user        haproxy
        group       haproxy
        daemon

        # turn on stats unix socket
        stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
    #use if not designated in their block
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    defaults
        mode                    http
        log                     global
        option                  httplog
        option                  dontlognull
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
        option                  redispatch
        retries                 3
        timeout http-request    10s
        timeout queue           1m
        timeout connect         10s
        timeout client          1m
        timeout server          1m
        timeout http-keep-alive 10s
        timeout check           10s
        maxconn                 10000


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    #HAProxy statistics backend
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    listen haproxy3-monitoring *:80
      mode    http
      option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
      option httpclose
      stats   enable
      stats   show-legends
      stats   refresh           5s
      stats   uri               /stats
      stats   realm             Haproxy\ Statistics
      stats   auth              username:password
      stats   admin             if TRUE

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # main frontend which proxys to the backends
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    frontend main
            bind *:80
            default_backend webapp-main

    # round robin balancing between the various backends
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    backend webapp-main
            balance roundrobin
            option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ example.uni.edu
            server  web1 10.10.1.21:80 check
            server  web2 10.10.1.22:80 check
```

web1 nginx - **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  10.10.1.21;


        # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/  =404;


        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }


        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }   

        location /dataroot/ {
            internal;
            alias /var/moodledata/; # ensure the path ends with /
        }

        location /cachedir/ {
            internal;
            alias /var/moodledata/cache/; # ensure the path ends with /
        }


        location /localcachedir/ {
            internal;
            alias /var/moodledata/localcache/; # ensure the path ends with /
        }

        location /tempdir/ {
            internal;
            alias /var/moodledata/temp/; # ensure the path ends with /
        }

        location /filedir/ {
            internal;
            alias /var/moodledata/filedir/; # ensure the path ends with /
        }

    }
```

web2 has the same configs as web1 along with its own local ip.

When I point directly the index.php  http://10.10.1.18/index.php it downloads the index.php file and gives

> 503 Service Unavailable

Anybody has similar experience issues like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked out, please follow these steps:

- do not use config files under /etc/nginx/conf.d/  only use 1 config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf like this

```
     # For more information on configuration, see:
        #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
        #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

        user nginx;
        worker_processes auto;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        pid /run/nginx.pid;

        events {
            worker_connections 8192;
        }

        http {
            log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

            access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
            tcp_nopush     on;
            sendfile            on;
            keepalive_timeout   65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;

            client_body_buffer_size 10K;
            client_header_buffer_size 1k;
            client_max_body_size 512m;
            large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

            client_body_timeout 1200;
            client_header_timeout 1200;
            send_timeout 100;

            include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type        application/octet-stream;

        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  example.uni.edu;

            # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            location / {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                index index.php;
            }
            error_page 404 /404.html;
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }

            location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }

            ###################### For Moodle Application ##################
            location /dataroot/ {
                internal;
                alias /var/moodledata/; # ensure the path ends with /
            }

            location /cachedir/ {
                internal;
                alias /var/moodledata/cache/; # ensure the path ends with /
            }


            location /localcachedir/ {
                internal;
                alias /var/moodledata/localcache/; # ensure the path ends with /
            }

            location /tempdir/ {
                internal;
                alias /var/moodledata/temp/; # ensure the path ends with /
            }

            location /filedir/ {
                internal;
                alias /var/moodledata/filedir/; # ensure the path ends with /
            }
            ###################### For Moodle Application ##################
        }
       }
```

- Make sure you use a valid haproxy config along with 2 different ports 80 is for backend and 8080 is to monitor the stats

```
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
    # full configuration options online.
    #
    #   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
    #
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Global settings
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    global
        # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
        # need to:
        #
        # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
        #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
        #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
        #
        # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
        #   file. A line like the following can be added to
        #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
        #
        #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
        #
        log         127.0.0.1 local2

        chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
        pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
        maxconn     10000
        user        haproxy
        group       haproxy
        daemon

        # turn on stats unix socket
        stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
    #use if not designated in their block
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    defaults
        mode                    http
        log                     global
        option                  httplog
        option                  dontlognull
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
        option                  redispatch
        retries                 3
        timeout http-request    10s
        timeout queue           1m
        timeout connect         10s
        timeout client          1m
        timeout server          1m
        timeout http-keep-alive 10s
        timeout check           10s
        maxconn                 10000


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    #HAProxy statistics backend
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    listen haproxy3-monitoring *:8080
      mode    http
      option forwardfor
      option httpclose
      stats   enable
      stats   show-legends
      stats   refresh           5s
      stats   uri               /stats
      stats   realm             Haproxy\ Statistics
      stats   auth              username:password
      stats   admin             if TRUE

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # main frontend which proxys to the backends
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    frontend main
            bind *:80
            option http-server-close
            option forwardfor
            default_backend webapp-main

    # round robin balancing between the various backends
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    backend webapp-main
            balance source
            option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ example.uni.edu
            server  web1 10.10.1.21:80 check
            server  web2 10.10.1.22:80 check
```

- Now you are fine to lookup your stats http://10.10.1.18:8080/  or http://example.uni.edu:8080/

You can also browse your application   http://example.uni.edu

Note: Make sure you public ip points to your haproxy server successfully!

Comment: i have an error when I used frontend main bind *:80 cannot bind 0.0.0.0:80 but when I used 8080 I there is not error why?

Comment: frontend main
               bind *:80
               option http-server-close
               option forwardfor
               default_backend webapp-main

Comment: oppss my bad netstat -anp | grep ":80" nginx using port 80 :D

Comment: @mehmetsen80 can see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986162/unable-to-figure-out-default-document-root-for-sub-domains-in-nginx